# Image appears differently in Safari, Firefox, and Chrome

Tags: browsers, images

[image]

This is a screenshot of the same image file on my website (viewing the image itself), in Firefox on the left, Safari in the middle and Chrome on the right. It appears as if Chrome has a more blue color in the image. Why is this?

- (Chrome Mac 28.0.1500.95)
- (Firefox 23.0 Mac)
- (Safari Version 5.1.10 (6534.59.10) Mac)

Comment: What type of image is it?

Comment: A basic .png image.

Comment: What's wrong though? It stills looks good.

Comment: It doesn't fit the company image and makes the pressed navbar image look out of place.

Comment: Maybe these browser(s) have a "problem" with the gAMA chunk in the PNG? I use [TweakPNG](http://entropymine.com/jason/tweakpng/) (Windows Tool) to remove the gAMA chunk to benefit versions of IE when an image must seamlessly blend with a background colour.

Answer (score 1):

this is a common issue for MAC and unfortunately there is no perfect solution. Possibly you are using different colour profile than the web standard. To minimize the difference save your images in sRGB profile. If you are using photoshop, in 'save for web' window, click the small arrow near the image file type. The other reason is variable gamma in PNG. As I said there is no perfect solution.

Comment: I am using [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net) for Windows to create my images. Can I use sRGB in Paint.NET?

Comment: Paint.NET do not include color profile however it support sRGB. That means, if you already have an image in sRGB and use Paint.NET to edit and save it, it will preserve sRGB color profile. But if you create an image from scratch in Paint.NET it will save the image RGB endoded **not sRGB**

Comment: To be clear, this is not a *problem* with Macs but a problem with creating proper color profiles.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this can be a problem with permissions on applications. You can view a fix here:

[How to Fix Screen Colour Changes in Mountain Lion](http://www.brilliantthinking.net/2012/08/06/how-to-fix-screen-colour-changes-in-mountain-lion-osx/)

1. Open the DISK UTILITY program in the UTILITIES folder under APPLICATIONS.
2. Click the REPAIR PERMISSIONS

(nut sure if applies to other versions of OS?)